# Using the map functions in R

Tags: r, maps

I imported an earthquake dataset and was using the map() and mapproj() libraries to plot the earthquakes points onto a map. But the problem Im having is if I want to isolate one country that I know has earthquake points in it, and run the code again, I can't get the points to show up! 
here's the (edit: entire) code I was using:

`library(maps)
library(mapproj)
EQpoints <- read.csv(file="C:\Users\User\Desktop\EQpoints.csv", head=TRUE, sep=",")
map("world",proj="mercator",xlim=c(-170,170))
points(mapproject(list(y=EQpoints[EQpoints$Magnitude>5,]$Latitude,         x=EQpoints[EQpoints$Magnitude>5,]$Longitude)),col=2,pch=".",cex=1)`

This works fine for mapping the points onto the earth but if I isolate, say, China like so:

`map("world","China",col="orange", bg="black")
points(mapproject(list(y=EQpoints[EQpoints$Magnitude>5,]$Latitude, x=EQpoints[EQpoints$Magnitude>5,]$Longitude)),col=2,pch=".",cex=1)`

The map of China appears but no data points show up?

Any suggestions as to how I'd fix this?

Also, I'm having issues where the map size sometimes changes size when I re-run the code? Any idea whats going on?

Thanks

EDIT: This is the output using dput():

```
structure(list(Magnitude = c(7.6, 6.9, 7.2, 8.3, 6.9), Latitude = c(52, 
50.71, 60, 60, 60), Longitude = c(172, -179.5, -150, -142, -142
)), .Names = c("Magnitude", "Latitude", "Longitude"), row.names = c(NA, 
5L), class = "data.frame")
```

Looking at the data, the first five entries are around Alaska

Comment: Please post reproducible code including sample dataset

Comment: The data set is .csv file on my computer that I downloaded from www.emdat.be   I can't give an exact link to it or anything because you do a specific query on that site and it allows you to download a .csv file of the data with the specific criteria. But I'll edit the main post to include the entire code.

Comment: Load your dataset into R. Enter `dput(head(yourdata, 5))` copy and paste that into your question.

Comment: I added dput(head(mydata,5) to the main question. Looking at the first 5 data points on the world map. The data points are near/in Alaska

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In you're second `map()` command (the China only map), you don't specify a projection! But you do call `mapproject` for the points. That will definitely not work. "`mapproject`" remembers the last projection used (try `.Last.projection()`), but if you don't specify a projection at all in the `map()` command, it doesn't get reset. So in the second call you're using `mercator` for the points, but lat/lon for the map.

Comment: Worked perfectly... I've only been  learning the map() functions recently, so it's all still a bit confusing. Thanks for your help!